# "infinite type" error in haskell, cannot find whats wrong

Tags: haskell, polynomials

i get this error

```
Polinomios.hs:117:125:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t0 = (t0, t1) -> t0
Expected type: (t0, t1)
  Actual type: ((t0, t1) -> t0, t1)
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `c'
In the expression: c : l
In the expression:
  if n == (snd $ head $ l) then
      ((k + fst $ head l), n) : (tail l)
  else
      c : l
```

I've already googled that and there is supposed to be a type error involved but im 99% sure there isnt. I know this has been asked before but i'm unable to solve this

```
adecentarPolinomio :: Polinomio -> Polinomio
adecentarPolinomio p@(Pol lista) = let f = \c@(k,n) l -> if n == (snd $ head $ l) then ((k + fst $ head l),n):(tail l) else c:l
                                   listaOrdenada = listaPol $ ordenarPolinomio p
                               in Pol (foldr f [last listaOrdenada] listaOrdenada)
```

code used:

```
data Coeficiente = C Int Int

data Polinomio = Pol [(Coeficiente,Grado)]

type Grado = Int


listaPol :: Polinomio -> [(Coeficiente, Int)]
listaPol (Pol l) = l

ordenarPolinomio :: Polinomio -> Polinomio
ordenarPolinomio (Pol lista) = Pol (sortBy (compare `on` snd) lista)

instance Num Coeficiente where
(+)  (C 0 a) (C 0 b) = C 0 (a+b)
(+)  (C n a) (C m b) = C n (mod (a+b) n)
(*)  (C 0 a) (C 0 b) = C 0 (a*b)
(*)  (C n a) (C m b) = C n (mod (a*b) n)
negate       (C 0 a) = C 0 (-a)
negate       (C n a) = C n (mod (-a) n)
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your question a little bit? How is the first code block is related to the last? Is it part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight problem with parentheses causing the type checker to infer an unexpected type.  First, your code a bit reformatted:

```
adecentarPolinomio :: Polinomio -> Polinomio
adecentarPolinomio p@(Pol lista) =
    let f c@(k,n) l =
            if n == (snd $ head $ l)
                then ((k + fst $ head l), n) : tail l
                else c : l
        listaOrdenada = listaPol $ ordenarPolinomio p
    in Pol (foldr f [last listaOrdenada] listaOrdenada)
```

Like this, I was able to almost immediately spot the error, namely that you have `(k + fst $ head l)` where you probably wanted `k + fst (head l)`.  Once I fixed that your code compiled.

I would like to point out that your `f` function has the potential to break because you're using `head` and `tail`, instead, consider

```
adecentarPolinomio :: Polinomio -> Polinomio
adecentarPolinomio p@(Pol lista) =
    let f c@(k,n) l@((k', n'):xs) =
            if n == n'
                then ((k + k'), n) : xs
                else c : l
        f c [] = [c]
        listaOrdenada = listaPol $ ordenarPolinomio p
    in Pol (foldr f [last listaOrdenada] listaOrdenada)
```

Now the function will handle empty lists, and you can avoid using `fst`, `snd`, `head`, and `tail`.

Answer (score 4):

I think `k + fst $ head l` is wrong. I believe it parses as `(k + fst) (head l)`, whereas I believe you meant `k + (fst $ head l)`.

Because of this, GHC is coming up with completely the wrong type for `c`, and getting terribly confused.